# Просадка fps в android приложении / Activity работает медленно

Tags: android, activity, recyclerview, android-asynctask, производительность

Добрый день! Столкнулся с проблемой: при работе MainActivity наблюдается просадка fps и отклик на нажатия с задержкой происходит. Если сделать long touch по CardView, то видно, как анимация нажатия рывками рисуется.
Я помещу весь код Activity, так как не знаю, что могло привести к подобным последствиям.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AllMenuData allMenuData;
private List<Cat> cats;

private int columns;

private Toolbar toolbar;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private CatAdapter catAdapter;
private List<CatCard> catCards;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarCat);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    try {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    updateData();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCat);

    catCards = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < cats.size(); i ++) {
        catCards.add(new CatCard
                (
                cats.get(i).getNameRu(),
                cats.get(i).getNameEn(),
                ImageStorage.getImage(cats.get(i).getPictureFileName())
                )
        );
    }

    catAdapter = new CatAdapter(catCards);

    if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        columns = 2;
    } else if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        columns = 4;
    } else {
        columns = 2;
    }

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, columns);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(catAdapter);

}

private void updateData () {
    allMenuData = ((MenuApp) getApplication()).getAllMenuData();
    cats = allMenuData.getCatsData().getCats();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateData();
    catAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Заметка: перед тем, как запустить это Activity, работает SplashActivity, в котором я выполняю AsyncTask-и. Но, как мне кажется, это не может быть связанно с этим. И вот почему: SplashActivity у меня наследует интерфейс AsyncResponseAllMenuData.

```
public interface AsyncResponseAllMenuData {
    void processFinish(AllMenuData output);
}
```

В конструктор самого AsyncTask я передаю объект этого Activity (AsyncResponseAllMenuData).
И по завершении его работы, вызываю метод `processFinish(AllMenuData output);`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(AllMenuData allMenuData) {
    asyncResponseAllMenuData.processFinish(allMenuData);
    super.onPostExecute(allMenuData);
}
```

Ну, и когда вызывается метод в SplashActivity, тогда стартует MainActivity:

```
private void startMainActivity () {
    ((MenuApp) getApplication()).setAllMenuData(allMenuData);
    this.startActivity(mainActivity);
    this.finish();
}

@Override
public void processFinish(AllMenuData output) {
    allMenuData = output;
    allMenuDataLoaded = true;
    startMainActivity();
}
```

И в заключение, есть ещё одна похожая по содержанию Activity, точно так же с RecyclerView и с такими же карточками как и в MainActivity, и она работает абсолютно нормально.

В чём может быть проблема?

**UPD**

Код адаптера:

```
public class CatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CatAdapter.CatViewHolder> {

private List<CatCard> cardList;

public CatAdapter(List<CatCard> cardList) {
    this.cardList = cardList;
}

public class CatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView titleRu, titleEn;
    public SquareImageView thumbnail;

    public CatViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        titleRu = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCatCardRu);
        titleEn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCatCardEn);
        thumbnail = (SquareImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivCatCard);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Activity activity = (Activity) view.getContext();
                Application app = activity.getApplication();
                int id = ((MenuApp) app).getAllMenuData().getCatsData().getCats().get(getAdapterPosition()).getId();
                startDishesActivity(view, id);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public CatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cat_card, parent, false);

    return new CatViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CatViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CatCard card = cardList.get(position);
    holder.titleRu.setText(card.getNameRU());
    holder.titleEn.setText(card.getNameEN());
    if (card.getImage() != null)
    holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(card.getImage());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cardList.size();
}

private void startDishesActivity (View v, int category) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DishesActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(TConst.intentCatKey, category);
    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

P.S. Я понимаю, что создавать для каждого View новый listener - это не верный подход, но неужели эти объекты настолько тяжелые, чтобы вызывать такие проблемы при списке размером в 4 View?

Comment: Покажите адаптер

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , добавил адаптер в вопрос.